# Change authentication procedure

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am creating a project and to first build it, I used the cookie-cutter of https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

This template has been useful for me but now I am trying to build an API for my project and I'm having some trouble with the authentication procedure.

Everything works fine but the process of a view getting authenticated by the token sent in the header. The view I'm speaking of is the following:

```
class HelloView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        content = {'message': 'Hello, World!'}
        return Response(content)
```

Then I just do a http request to the respective URL sending the token like:

```
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/hello/ 'Authorization: Token 8b59a60cd91c29f4e2a7be54fbd6d32c7bd57377'
```

Then, the response I get is:

```
{
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Then if I enter the URL using the browser it would say the same unless I have previously logged in the Django admin. For this reason, I think what happens basically is some problem of configuration in the authentication procedure. I have added the following variables to my settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
],
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
]
}
```

But I haven't changed anything from the cookiecutter template authentication so as I said, I think that's where the issue may be although I don't know how to solve it.

My final question is, do you know how to change the way the authentication is done given a permission class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want user to authenticate using a token. So you  need to set the token authentication in the settings:

```
  "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
    ),
```

Or if you want just one view to use the token authentication, and not default for all views, you can use `authentication_classes` variable in your view.